# Java BigDecimal setScale used with RoundingMode.CEILING

Tags: java, math, rounding, bigdecimal

I have created the following helper function for rounding decimals:

```
public static double round(double value, int places, RoundingMode roundingMode) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, roundingMode);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

I am confused by the results I get when using `RoundingMode.CEILING`:

```
round(2.0, 0, RoundingMode.CEILING); // returns 2, which is expected
round(2.180, 2, RoundingMode.CEILING); // returns 2.19, which seems odd as I expected 2.18
```

Could somebody please explain why in the second call, the value is effectively rounded up to 2.19?

Comment: Have you check how you `bd` looks like when you use `2.180`? You should/might get a value like `2.180000000000000159872115546022541821002960205078125`.

Comment: The problem here is that the decimal number 2.180 (in contrast to 2.0) does not have an exact representation as a double value. It happens, the nearest double value is slightly larger.

Comment: @Tom you are right, indeed the 2.180 value is being approximated before being scaled/rounded. Any ideas how to best fix the round() method to correct for this issue when using `RoundingMode.CEILING` and `RoundingMode.FLOOR`?

Comment: what happens when you use the String constructor, `new BigDecimal("2.180")`?

Comment: @JamesKPolk That would work, because it already applies a scale and would therefore "ignore" the inaccuracy. OP could also use `new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(value))`.

Comment: @JamesKPolk - that works. Thank you!